# How to open a url in Safari from my Today Extension within my app using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, today-extension

I have a Today extension and let say I just want to open a url `let url = "https://google.com"` when I press the button `goButton` in my widget to open it in my app with safari ( inside my app using `SafariServices` )

I have defined a custom url scheme in my Info.plist and I wrote those lines of code in my button (`class TodayViewController`) :

```
@IBAction func goButton(_ sender: Any) {
    let myAppUrl = URL(string: "Easy-tools://")!
    extensionContext?.open(myAppUrl, completionHandler: { (success) in
        if (!success) {
            print("error: failed to open app from Today Extension")
        }
    })
}
```

I have sucssesfuly open my main app from my widget but i don't know how to open the url `let url = "https://google.com"` when i press `goButton` I have added this func in my AppDelegate file :

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool
```

but i don't know how to open it , by the way I'm new in swift

Answer (score 0):

So this is actually a question about SafariServices rather than about Today extensions?

By saying that you are "new in swift" do you mean that you have worked with iOS before but used Objective-C instead?

I assume that you have read the [SafariServices documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices). I have not used it yet, but I think it should work like this:

1. Implement `application(_:open:options:)` (the one you mention above) and [initialize](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/sfsafariviewcontroller/1649141-init) an `SFSafariViewController` using your URL.
2. Present your safari view controller or push it onto a navigation stack, just like any other view controller.

Apps created from Xcode templates have some kind of root view controller set up for you, so you can use that for presentation before you figure out where exactly you want to present your safari view.